# tooltip inside a dropdown-menu is hiding below dropdown

Tags: html, css, angular2-directives

i have dropdown and inside it i am showing tooltip on hover of a text.But it is showing below the dropdown though z-index of tooltip is more than it's parent dropdown.

Comment: Show the code here [learn from here how to ask a question here](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 0):

Try with `container` setting it to `body`..
Like this:

```
$(selector).tooltip({
    container: 'body' //<--- use the container option
});
```